# How can I provide composer with a twig version that it's okay with, so I can roll back Drupal to a version that will work with PHP 7.4?

Tags: 9, composer

I inherited a broken Drupal 9 site.  Drush could not be made to work, so I deleted the vendor directory, renamed composer.lock and reinstalled.  This has worked for me before on broken sites. Now I whitescreen when I log onto the site (which works well for anonymous users)

Because I still don't have drush, and I can't log in to the site, I can't flush the cache.
Running mysite.com/update.php shows an error saying I need PHP 8.0.  I'm on a shared host and upgrading php aby a major verison seems dangerous.

When I try to revert with composer require drupal/core-recommended:9.3.6  I get

```
 Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.15.3, v2.14.11].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.14.11, v2.15.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.14.11, v2.15.3].
    - drupal/core-recommended 9.3.6 requires twig/twig v2.14.11 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.14.11].
    - Installation request for drupal/core-recommended 9.3.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[9.3.6].
    - Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v2.15.3) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.15.3].
```

I've deleted composer.lock and explicitly removed twig/twig with `composer remove twig/twig`.

There has to be a way to salvage this, but nothing seems to work.
The composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "vardot/varbase-project",
    "version": "dev-master",
    "version_normalized": "9999999-dev",
    "require": {
        "ajaxorg/ace-builds": "master",
        "components/highlightjs": "^9.16",
        "composer/installers": "~1.0 || ~2.0",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/address": "^1.9",
        "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.6",
        "drupal/asset_injector": "^2.7",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.23",
        "drupal/captcha": "^1.2",
        "drupal/ckeditor_media_embed": "^1.10",
        "drupal/config_direct_save": "^2.1",
        "drupal/content_moderation_notifications": "^3.3",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/devel_entity_updates": "^3.0",
        "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.5",
        "drupal/drupal-library-installer-plugin": "^0.3.0",
        "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^2.0",
        "drupal/easy_install": "^10.5",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.6",
        "drupal/entity_clone": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/entity_print": "^2.4",
        "drupal/features": "^3.12",
        "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.19",
        "drupal/fontyourface": "^3.6",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.1",
        "drupal/google_analytics_reports": "^3.0@RC",
        "drupal/google_tag": "^1.4",
        "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
        "drupal/image_resize_filter": "^1.1",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_checkboxradio": "^1.2",
        "drupal/l10n_client": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/libraries": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/login_destination": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/mail_edit": "2.0.x-dev",
        "drupal/mailchimp": "^2.0",
        "drupal/memcache": "^2.3",
        "drupal/menu_block": "^1.7",
        "drupal/menu_position": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/migrate_file_to_media": "^2.0",
        "drupal/migrate_tools": "^5.0",
        "drupal/node_edit_protection": "^1.0",
        "drupal/panelizer": "^4.4",
        "drupal/password_policy": "^3.0",
        "drupal/pathologic": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/permissions_by_term": "^3.1",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.0",
        "drupal/recreate_block_content": "^2.1",
        "drupal/redirect_after_login": "^2.7",
        "drupal/redis": "^1.5",
        "drupal/rename_admin_paths": "^2.0",
        "drupal/responsive_menu": "^4.4",
        "drupal/rules": "3.x-dev",
        "drupal/scheduler": "^1.4",
        "drupal/search_api_page": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/seckit": "^2.0",
        "drupal/security_review": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/sendgrid_integration": "^1.7",
        "drupal/slick": "^2.3",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.0",
        "drupal/tour_ui": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/tvi": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^3.1",
        "drupal/type_style": "^1.0",
        "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/varbase_total_control": "^9.0",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.4",
        "drupal/video_embed_media": "^2.4",
        "drupal/video_embed_wysiwyg": "^2.4",
        "drupal/views_bootstrap": "^4.3",
        "drupal/views_field_formatter": "^1.13",
        "drupal/views_field_view": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/we_megamenu": "^1.13",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.0",
        "drupal/webform_mailchimp": "^5.9",
        "drupal/weight": "^3.3",
        "enyo/dropzone": "^5.9",
        "kenwheeler/slick": "^1.6",
        "mbostock/d3": "^3.5",
        "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "^2.5",
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.4",
        "vardot/varbase": "^9.0",
        "vardot/varbase-updater": "^2.0",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.2",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
        "drupal/views_fieldsets": "3.x-dev",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_datepicker": "^1.1",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_accordion": "^1.1",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_draggable": "^1.2",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_droppable": "^1.2",
        "drupal/purge": "^3.2",
        "drupal/varnish_purge": "^2.1",
        "drupal/quick_node_clone": "^1.14",
        "drupal/antibot": "^2.0",
        "drupal/flood_control": "^2.2",
        "drupal/config_filter": "^2.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mglaman/drupal-check": "^1.1"
    },
    "type": "project",
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "allowed-packages": [
                "drupal/core"
            ],
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "patches": {
            "drupal/l10n_client": {
                "#3178812 - Drupal 9 Compatibility for l10n_client module": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-10-25/3178812_l10n_client_d9_compatibility_fixes.patch"
        }
        },
        "patches-ignore": [],
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Varbase codebase </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the vardot/varbase-project template!              </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://docs.varbase.vardot.com",
                "  * Get support: https://www.vardot.com/en/form/get-support-varbase",
                "  * Join Our Slack Team for Feedback and Support:",
                "      http://slack.varbase.vardot.com",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        },
        "_readme": [
            "NOTICE: We're now using composer patches from Vardot repository to suggest",
            "several fixes and better handling of patches in your Drupal project.",
            "You'll notice that we have included (https://github.com/vardot/composer-patches)",
            "in this composer.json repositories. This will replace the original",
            "library (cweagans/composer-patches) with our own from (vardot/composer-patches).",
            "See https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches/pull/243 and more details",
            "on our changes on the composer-patches package. Once our changes get merged,",
            "we will revert to using (cweagans/composer-patches) without this override."
        ],
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-9.0.x": "9.0.x-dev",
            "dev-10.0.x": "10.0.x-dev"
        },
        "installer-types": [
            "bower-asset",
            "npm-asset"
        ],
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/profiles/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "web/libraries/slick": [
                "npm-asset/slick-carousel"
            ],
            "web/libraries/ace": [
                "npm-asset/ace-builds"
            ],
            "web/libraries/jquery-ui-touch-punch": [
                "bower-asset/jqueryui-touch-punch"
            ],
            "web/libraries/swagger-ui/dist": [
                "npm-asset/swagger-ui-dist"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library",
                "type:bower-asset",
                "type:npm-asset"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-libraries": {
            "library-directory": "web/libraries",
            "libraries": [
                {
                    "name": "objectfitpolyfill",
                    "package": "bower-asset/objectfitpolyfill"
                },
                {
                    "name": "chartjs",
                    "package": "bower-asset/chartjs"
                },
                {
                    "name": "c3",
                    "package": "bower-asset/c3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "d3",
                    "package": "bower-asset/d3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "dropzone",
                    "package": "npm-asset/dropzone"
                },
                {
                    "name": "blazy",
                    "package": "npm-asset/blazy"
                },
                {
                    "name": "slick",
                    "package": "npm-asset/slick-carousel"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ace",
                    "package": "npm-asset/ace-builds"
                },
                {
                    "name": "jquery-ui-touch-punch",
                    "package": "bower-asset/jqueryui-touch-punch"
                },
                {
                    "name": "imagesloaded",
                    "package": "npm-asset/imagesloaded"
                },
                {
                    "name": "swagger-ui",
                    "package": "npm-asset/swagger-ui-dist"
                }
            ]
        },
        "enable-patching": true,
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Varbase\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles",
            "Varbase\\composer\\ScriptHandler::removeGitDirectories"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Varbase\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles",
            "Varbase\\composer\\ScriptHandler::removeGitDirectories"
        ],
        "post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
            "Varbase\\composer\\ScriptHandler::postDrupalScaffoldProcedure"
        ]
    },
    "license": [
        "GPL-2.0-or-later"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Vardot",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/vardot",
            "role": "Maintainer"
        }
    ],
    "description": "Project template for Varbase distribution.",
    "repositories": {
        "2": {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "enyo/dropzone",
                "version": "master",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/enyo/dropzone.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "kenwheeler/slick",
                "version": "master",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        },
        "0": {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "ajaxorg/ace-builds",
                "version": "master",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        },
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "assets": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        },
        "composer-patches": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/vardot/composer-patches"
        },
        "packagist.org": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https?://repo.packagist.org",
            "allow_ssl_downgrade": true
        }
    },
    "support": {
        "issues": "http://drupal.org/project/issues/varbase",
        "source": "http://cgit.drupalcode.org/varbase"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": true,
            "drupal/drupal-library-installer-plugin": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": true,
            "rvtraveller/qs-composer-installer": true,
            "vardot/varbase-updater": true,
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true
        },
        "vendor-dir": "vendor"
    }
}
```

The error when I try to run drush is

```
PHP Warning:  pcntl_exec(): Error has occurred: (errno 8) Exec format error in /usr/local/src/drush/includes/startup.inc on line 422
Error has occurred executing the Drush script found at /var/www/vhosts/mysite/vendor/bin/drush.launcher
```

The error pulled from watchdog in the database is

```
Argument 3 passed to Drupal\update_helper\Updater::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\Core\Extension\ThemeInstallerInterface, instance of Drupal\config_update\ConfigReverter given, called in /var/www/vhosts/qe2foundation.ca/qe2/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 262";s:9:"%function";s:43:"Drupal\update_helper\Updater->__construct()";s:5:"%file";s:86:"/var/www/vhosts/mysite/somedir/web/modules/contrib/update_helper/src/Updater.php
```

How can I provide composer with a twig version that it's okay with, so I can roll back Drupal to a version that will work with PHP 7.4?

Comment: As always with Composer questions, not including a `composer.json` file will result in the question being downvoted and likely closed. In addition you did not include the exception log associated with the white screen. We can’t answer the question as-is. Also: what is the question?

Comment: You probably need to add the `-W` flag, which will also update any dependencies of the library.

Comment: Also, never update on a live site.  Even if you don't have a local dev environment set up and you are not using version control, you can update `composer.json` and `composer.lock` locally as long as you have composer installed, and then upload the files to the server and run `composer install`.

Comment: Do `composer require drupal/core-recommended:9.3.6 -W` as Jaypan said. If that doesn't work, then try `composer require drupal/core-recommended:9.3.6 twig/twig:2.14.11 -W`